# Erro na hora que inicia o spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Primeiro de tudo, uso o java 9 e o apache tomcat 9
Quando inicio a aplicação acontece este erro:

> ```
> 18:00:46,804 ERROR DispatcherServlet:492 - Context initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1090)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:980)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>     at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:252)
>     at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:143)
>     at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:266)
>     at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>     ... 49 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
>     ... 55 more
> dez 27, 2017 6:00:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
> GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1090)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:980)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>     at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:252)
>     at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:143)
>     at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:266)
>     at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>     ... 49 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
>     ... 55 more    
> dez 27, 2017 6:00:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
> GRAVE: Servlet [spring mvc] in web application [/contas] threw load() exception
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
>     at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:252)
>     at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:143)
>     at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:266)
>     at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1090)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:980)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
> ```

Acredito que o erro esteje aqui no web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>contas</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Declaracao do servlet do Spring MVC abaixo-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.caelum.contas" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Dependências:

[image: Imagem de todas as dependências do projeto]

Como da erro antes de chamar qualque código, acho que só isso já é suficiente de informação

Esse projeto foi criado no java 7 e com apache 7...

Comment: Tenho certeza que essa pergunta é duplicata, mas não consigo achar a relacionada. O problema é que o JAXB não está mais no classpath padão do Java 9 e deve ser adicionado a ele.

Comment: se for isso, que falta o JAXB sei como resolver. Como neste link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260238/hibernate-com-java-9

Comment: Isso mesmo. A correção funciona?

Comment: Funcionou! agora está ok

Comment: Por favor faça um comentário com a resposta para eu deixar como resolvido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o JAXB não está mais no classpath padrão do Java 9 e deve ser adicionado a ele.

No maven, é isso:

```xml
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```